# Configuring a HTTP Proxy for TYPO3 8.7

Tags: typo3, guzzle, typo3-8.x

When I try to update the list of extensions I get the following error:

"Could not access remote resource https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz."

The server needs a http proxy to download resources from the internet. My proxy config in LocalConfiguration.php looks like this:

```
'HTTP' => [
    'proxy' => [
        'http' => 'http://www.myproxy...:80',
     ],
],
```

The proxy worked fine with TYPO3 7.6 but the [config has changed since TYPO3 8.1](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.1/Breaking-70056-CurlAndHttpRequestRemoved.html?highlight=proxy_host). The proxy also works fine in php with "stream_context_create( ...".

I couldn't find much information (e.g. example) on how to properly configure the proxy in the LocalConfiguration.php of TYPO3 8. Does anybody have a working example?

The for the system curl the proxy is already configured and works. Is there a way to use that? That configuration has also changed since 7.6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `https` instead of `http` as config key?

Comment: The list is still not loading but the error message is different ("No data available in table). In addition the backend has fetched a new core update. That suggests that the proxy is working now.